# My app crashes when lightweight Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration

I have created a new version of Core Data Model with a  non-optional ‘new attribute’.
When I run my app in previous build. My app crashes.

can you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the default value of your 'new attribute'. If you don't set default value then the 'new attribute' will be assigned by a nil value which eventually crashes your app.

```
 NSString *yourAttribute = @"Default";
```